# Count size of rolling intersection in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` that consists of group labels ('B') and elements of each group ('A'). The group labels are ordered, and I want to know how many elements of group I show up in group i+1.

An example:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({ 'A': ['a','b','c','a','c','a','d'], 'B' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3]})

   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  1
2  c  1
3  a  2
4  c  2
5  a  3
6  d  3
```

The desired output would be something like:

```
B
1  NaN
2  2
3  1
```

One way to go about this would be to compute the number of distinct elements in the union of group I and group i+1 and then subtract of the number of distinct elements in each group. I've tried:

```
pd.rolling_apply(grp['A'], lambda x: len(x.unique()),2)
```

but this produces an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'type'
```

How do I get this to work with `rolling_apply` or is there a better way to attack this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach with using sets and shifting the result:

First grouping the dataframe and then converting column A of each group into a set:

```
In [86]: grp = df.groupby('B')
In [87]: s = grp.apply(lambda x : set(x['A']))
In [88]: s
Out[88]: 
B
1    set([a, c, b])
2       set([a, c])
3       set([a, d])
dtype: object
```

To calculate the intersection between consecutive sets, make a shifted version (I replace the NaN to an empty set for the next step):

```
In [89]: s2 = s.shift(1).fillna(set([]))
In [90]: s2
Out[90]: 
B
1           set([])
2    set([a, c, b])
3       set([a, c])
dtype: object
```

Combine both series and calculate the length of the intersection:

```
In [91]: s.combine(s2, lambda x, y: len(x.intersection(y)))
Out[91]: 
B
1    0
2    2
3    1
dtype: object
```

Another way to do the last step (for sets `&` means `intersection`):

```
df = pd.concat([s, s2], axis=1)
df.apply(lambda x: len(x[0] & x[1]), axis=1)
```

---

The reason the rolling apply does not work is because 1) you provided it a GroupBy object and not a series, and 2) it only works with numerical values.

Comment: This is fiddly stuff! (I think using combine here is clever)

Comment: @AndyHayden Yes, thinking of the combine was the hard part :-). For set difference, `s - s2` does work, but intersection as `s & s2` seems not to work for pandas serieses. I was looking for a way to apply a function on the elements of two serieses, but didn't find an obvious one.